# Using a shtender without permission?

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, borrowing, shtender

In many shuls people bring their private shtenders to use during davening or learning. Is it permissible to use someone's shtender in their absence without asking permission first?

Comment: Why should it be different than any other object? Is it being used for a mitzvah that can’t be done otherwise?

Comment: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Borrowing_without_Permission There is a disagreement about whether it is permitted to borrow someone's sefer, but many modern poskim tend towards allowing people to borrow other's seforim without permission.

Comment: I think it's assumed that people have permission to use the shtender while it is in its place.

Comment: I heard in the name of Rav Moshe Feinstein that a sefer left in a Beis Medrash that's not on a designated shelf  may be used unless marked otherwise because if someone really cared about his items being used he wouldn't leave them in a public area. Presumably the same would be true about a shtender. Ask you LOR